# Which ring represents the kernel of this homomorphism of group schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, group-schemes

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[X,X^{-1}]$, and let $\mathbb{G}_m = \textrm{Spec } R$.  If $A$ is a ring, the set of $A$-rational points $$\textrm{G}_m(A) = \textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Sch}}(\textrm{Spec } A, \mathbb{G}_m) = \textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Ring}}(R,A)$$

can be identified with $A^{\ast}$.  Fix an integer $N \geq 1$, and consider the morphism of schemes $f: \mathbb{G}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$ corresponding to the ring homomorphism $R \rightarrow R, X \mapsto X^N$.  Then for any ring $A$, $f(A): A^{\ast} \rightarrow A^{\ast}$ is the map $x \mapsto x^N$, so $f$ is a homomorphism of group schemes.

If $e: \textrm{Spec } \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$ is the identity section (the morphism of schemes corresponding to homomorphism $R \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}, X \mapsto 1 $), then the scheme-theoretic kernel $K$ of $f$ is the fiber product

$$\mathbb{G}_m \times_{\mathbb{G}_m} \textrm{Spec } \mathbb{Z}$$ via the maps $f$ and $e$.  If $\pi: K \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$ is the projection morphism, then for each ring $A$, the image of  $\pi(A): K(A) \rightarrow A^{\ast}$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $f(A)$.  This follows by universal property of the fiber product.

I have two questions about this:

1 .  Is there is a nicer description of the ring $\mathcal O_K(K)$ whose spectrum is $K$?  What we have is that $\mathcal O_K(K)$ is the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X,X^{-1}] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[X,X^{-1}]} \mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbb{Z}[X,X^{-1}]$ is a module over itself via $f(X) \cdot g(X) = f(X^N)g(X)$, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a module over $\mathbb{Z}[X,X^{-1}]$ via $f(X) \cdot n = f(1)n$.

2 .  Is $\pi(A): K(A) \rightarrow A^{\ast}$ an injection for each ring $A$?  Moreover, we usually think of a kernel as being a closed subgroup.  Is the projection map $K \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$ a closed immersion?

Comment: Is it not just $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^N-1)$?

Comment: @D_S Did you read my answer? Does it make sense? Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\text{}$1. As you see from your description, $$\mathcal{O}_K \cong \mathbb{Z}[X, X^{-1}]/(X^N - 1).$$Agree?

$\text{}$2. Yes, $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$ is a closed immersion, in fact given by the equation $X^n - 1 = 0$. The question in the first line of (2) you have answered in your introduction: yes,$$K(A) = \left\{x \in A^\times : x^n = 1\right\} \subset A^\times.$$